# The transaction log for database is full due to 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, transaction-log

We are facing problems related to transaction logs becoming full.

> The transaction log for database is full due to 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION'

My database logs are becoming full after every 4-5 days & after that 
for sometime all queries start failing. This state remains for sometime(2-3 min max). After that log space gets freed up & everything comes back to normal again. This has become a recurring issue which happens randomly.
Initially we thought that's its a temporary issue occurred because of some temporary SQL job & did `SHRINKDATABASE` for 1-2 times. It worked for that time. But nowadays we are facing this issue again & again & its so random that we are not able to identify what query is causing this issue.

We tried looking for expensive queries which might have caused this issue & tried to rerun again to reproduce the same issue but it didn't worked. I tried searching for this problem but every answer is about shrinking log files. I know that doing `SHRINKDATABASE` every time is not the correct solution. I want to find the exact cause of this issue.

How can I find the exact query which is causing the issue? Or what approach I should adopt to get solution for this problem?

Server details :

- Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64)
- Recovery Model : Simple
- OS : Windows Server 2012 R2
- Running on Intel Xenon CPU E5-2630 v3 @2.40GHz, 16 cores
- Installed memory - 128 GB

Comment: Sounds like you have a long-running transaction.

Comment: [`DBCC OPENTRAN()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182792.aspx), and don't ever use `SHRINKDATABASE` use `SHRINKFILE` to target *only the log file*, and *only in an emergency*. Also, why are you on RTM? SP1 was released last May and there have been [5 important cumulative updates since then](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/team-posts/latest-builds-sql-server-2014/).